# Google Charts format currency without cent values

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, google-visualization

I am currently working on a project that uses the Google Visualization API. I have formatted the values on the y-axis of my chart to display in currency using `vAxis: {format: 'currency'}` in my `options`, but I can't figure out how to remove the cent values.

Here is what my chart looks like:
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Xvo.png)

Here are my `options`:

```
var options = {
      chartArea: {width: '90%', height: '80%'},
      vAxis: {format: 'currency', ticks: [0, 20000, 40000, 60000]},
      colors: ['#4285f4'],
      legend: {position: 'none'}
    };
```

On the `vAxis` it shows marks at $0.00, $20,000.00, $40,000.00, and $60,000.00, but I want it to show marks at $0, $20,000, $40,000, and $60,000.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a custom format option...

```
format: '$#,##0'
```

or you can provide both the value and formatted value in the ticks option...

```
ticks: [
  {v: 0, f: '$0'},
  {v: 20000, f: '$20,000'},
  {v: 40000, f: '$40,000'},
  {v: 60000, f: '$60,000'}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

apply toFixed() method on your currencies. You can specify number of decimal places you prefer in brackets. For example variable.toFixed(2).

Comment: How do I apply the toFixed() method on the numbers that I'm passing into my options though? Google Visualization is already formatting the numbers given these values: vAxis: {format: 'currency', ticks: [0, 20000, 40000, 60000]}.